# Does this snippet cause an infinite loop?

Tags: android

I'm not sure. I created this code that crashes only on device < 2.3.x. Is this code causes a loop?

```
SharedPreferences prefs3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
          public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String listpref) {       
                preferenze();

              }   };

private void preferenze() {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        CheckboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
        ListPreference = prefs.getString("listpref", "");
        numeronotifiche = prefs.getString("notify", "");
        Sound = prefs.getString("sound", "");
        barranotifiche = prefs.getBoolean("keep", false);
```

Comment: Why you got that question?

Comment: why with this code on android < 2.3 when I rotate screen my app crashes. Only with android < 2.3

Comment: Take a look at the stacktrace and maybe post it - then maybe we can answer your question...

Comment: Are you seeing any stackoverflow errors? If not I don't think it is due to infinite loop. Stack trace may help.

Comment: sorry: what is stacktrace?

Comment: You might want to change your ``void preferenze()`` method to ``void preferenze(SharedPreferences prefs)`` and pass the ``prefs`` value from observer to it.

Comment: Stacktrace is another word for log cat, look here if you don't know what the log cat is - http://www.appaholics.in/using-the-logcat/

Comment: @harism, can you tell me an example to do this? preferenze(SharedPreferences prefs) how I pass value to observer? thanks!